# integrating 2nd order partial differential

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I want to solve the following:
$$
\partial_{tt} H(x,t)=2ce^{-t}
$$
I would like to know if my method of working is correct

$$
\partial_tH(x,t)=-2cte^{-t}+K(t)
$$
$$
H(x,t)=2ct^2e^{-t}+\int{K(t)}dt+F(t)
$$
where $K(t)$ and $F(t)$ are constants of integration.

Comment: The constant is $x$-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are constants with respect to time, $K \neq K(t), F \neq F(t) $ but instead, as mentioned in the comment, $K = K (x), F = F(x)$.
Note also that $\partial_t -te^{-t} =-e^{-t} + te^{-t}\neq e^{-t}$. Thus
\begin{align} \partial_t H(x, t) &= -2 ce^{-t} + K(x) \\
\Rightarrow H(x, t) &= 2 ce^{-t} + K(x)t + F(x) 
\end{align}